# install YCM error: python site module not loaded

Tags: python, vim, homebrew, macvim, youcompleteme

So I really wanted to try YCM, which has been said to be a great plugin for Vim. I have been spending several hours on installation and cannot succeed due to the error of `E887: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python's site module could not be loaded.`

I installed MacVim, Vim, and Python using Homebrew. I reinstalled them so many times and still cannot get it done -- as many people suggested in the issues on YCM GitHub page.

My OS version is MacOS Sierra (10.12).

`which python` returns `/usr/local/bin/python` and `python --version` gives `Python 2.7.12`. Typing `:echo has('python')` returns 1.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I had this same problem on Sierra, home-brew seems to be placing the latest python here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_1/Frameworks
```

But `brew install vim` ends up trying to link to python from the wrong directory. Looking at `vim --version | grep python` I saw:

```
-lc -F/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks -framework Python
```

(see `vim --version | grep python`)

To fix this, I did the following;

```
brew uninstall python vim
brew install python
brew install vim --build-from-source
```

Now, `vim --version | grep python` shows vim is correctly linked to the correct python Framework dir.

Comment: Yay, thanks so much! Now it finally successfully isntalled. However, I got Python crashed whenever I launch vim. I am searching for that now. Any idea?

Comment: could be an issue with one of your plugins, try disabling them all, and enabling one by one, or launch vim naked with defaults using:  `vim  --noplugin`

Comment: actually I tried to start fresh so only vundle and YCM are in the list. Is macvim necessary (as mentioned in YCM's documentation page) or just vim is enough?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about YCM, I don't use it and prefer UltiSnips myself.

Comment: Thanks anyway! You help me solve the biggest problem!

Answer (score 2):

This issue usually happens when recompiling python after vim, try to just reinstall vim & macvim, the issue might get resolved.

```
$ brew reinstall vim macvim
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but as the question states, I have already reinstalled them many many times but still got the same E877 error.

Comment: This one helped fix my problem. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

While @Matthew Hutchinson's answer help me got vim and python connected, I found the answer in this [issue of YCM](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/620) stop Python from crashing by the command `export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1`, thanks to [Koepsell](https://github.com/koepsell)